# How to protect stone masonry wall from weather

Tags: walls, adhesive, masonry, weather-resistant

My external walls are made from natural stone and they were built in 1900. The weather has stripped the paint off and is causing wear to the wall. The current paint used on the wall is a matt black which has faded.

For the window seals I applied PVA glue as a protector and to leave a natural look. Only problem is the glue returns to normal state when freezing outside.

**I would like to protect my external wall from the weather, how can I do this?**. I would preferably like it to be a natural look. Is there a glue that works during freezing? Should I just buy a black masonry paint which will stand out? Or does anyone have any other ideas?

I have searched online but still unsure. Thanks.

Comment: I guess some pictures would be helpful. Because where I grew up external walls of stone are perfectly normal and withstand the elements way better than plastered ones. So it depends on the stone, the climate and the paint.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need some more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @Erik - Where I live, upstate NY near the PA border, the problem is that cracks open up *between* the stones.  I don't know if this is Adam's problem, though.  What I am planning to use when the weather is warmer, and I have done some repointing, is the Behr premium concrete & masonry protector & waterproofer.  It is transparent.

Comment: Hi @aparente001 . Masonry protector will help because it will prevent most of the water from going too deep into the stone. You can add anti freeze and water protection liquid to the pointing cement mix. I answered my question with my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I visited my local paint shop and got a handful of paint cards to match against the current paint. I selected the paint and had it mixed up to good quality. It is a dark grey which is common in my area. I brushed off any loose sand from the stone before painting. Areas that were falling off in lumps I put PVA glue mixed with a small amount of water on it.

You can then paint over that area if need to. I will have to keep on top of painting the lower part of the wall. It will protect against rain and wind.

The problem was the stone was going soft and flaking off. I wanted to know how to protect the stone from the weather. This seems to work. It is worth paying for the paint because it is very expensive to have to outer wall rebuilt. The wall was down the side of the house with a walkway so you do not see it. It was the bottom that got the worst of it.